# Solving problems involving powers

Tags: power-series, problem-solving

How to reach from

$1+= [1+×]^1/​t  $

the power is (1/T)

to

$$APR = \frac{\ (1+EAR)^T - 1 \ }{T}$$

$$1+EAR=[1+T\times APR]^{1/T}\\ APR=\frac {(1+EAR)^T-1}T$$

---

and the same goes here:

$Var(aX) + Var(bY) + 2cov(aX,bY) = a^2var(X) + b^2var(Y) + 2abcov(X,Y)  $

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBqZY.png)

---

It's supposed to be mathematically simple, maybe a concept is missing for me, so I'd really appreciate if it's solved showing details as much as possible. Thanks

Comment: For the first one is solving the first equation to APR, what are the steps?  The second one also is similar, some steps have been done to reach from the first equation to the second one. Can you solve them? Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Those are two questions, the first one: is solving 1+EAR=[1+T×APR]^1/​T to get APR. Finally APR=(1+EAR)^T −1 / T, my question is how? Actually T and t are the same. you can ignore "the power is (1/T)" part as I was trying to clarify the power is 1/T as it might not be clear. The second one is: Var(aX)+Var(bY)+2cov(aX,bY) should be equal to a^2var(X)+b^2var(Y)+2abcov(X,Y), also my question is how it was solved to reach this?

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with $1+= (1+ \times )^\frac{1}{T}$, the crucial step is to raise both sides of the equation to the power $T$ : this gives the equivalent equation 
$$ (1+EAR)^T = 1+ \times $$ from which after simple algebraic cancellations you can deduce the end result.

For the second part of your question, this has nothing to do with powers, really, and everything to do with properties of the Variance and Covariance, namely,

$$\operatorname{Var}(aX) = a^2 \operatorname{Var}(X)$$ and
\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}(aX, Y) = a\ \operatorname{cov}(X,Y)\\
\operatorname{cov}(X, bY) = b\ \operatorname{cov}(X,Y)\\
\end{align}

I hope this answers your questions(s). If not, I can give more details.

EDIT

From the definition of the variance,

$\operatorname{Var}(X) = \sum_s p(s) (X(s) - \operatorname{E}[X])^2$,

you get

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[aX] &= \sum_s p(s) (aX(s) - \operatorname{E}[aX])^2\\
   &= \sum_s p(s) \left(a X(s) - a \operatorname{E}[X]\right)^2\\
&\text{(since the expected value is linear w.r.t. its variable)}\\
   &= \sum_s p(s) a^2 \left(X(s) - \operatorname{E}[X]\right)^2\\
   &= a^2 \operatorname{Var}[X]\\
\end{align}

and similarly for the covariance.

Comment: Thanks lmsteffan, the first one is now clarified. Can you explain which properties of the variance and covariance that led to this? My starting point is     http://i.imgur.com/RVc2dTy.png?1

Comment: @user274094 I have added some explanations to my answer.